Loading module was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type("text/html")
I am unable to import GLTFLoader into my threejs website & it's showing the same error again and again i.e.
" Loading module "http://127.0.0.1:5500/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/node_modules/three" was    blocked because of a disallowed MIME type("text/html") ".
This is my main.js code:-
             import * as THREE from "./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js";
            import {GLTFLoader} from "./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
            // Basic Three.js setup
            const scene= new THREE.Scene();
            const camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75,0.1,1000);                                               
            const renderer= new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            canvas: document.querySelector('#bg'),
            });
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
            camera.position.setZ(30);
            renderer.render(scene,camera);
            // Load the GLB model
            const loader= new GLTFLoader();
            loader.load('C:\Users\User\Desktop\realistic_human_heart.glb', (gltf) => {
            const heart = gltf.scene;
            scene.add(heart);
            heart.position.set(0, 0, 0); // Center the model 
            }, undefined, (error) => {
            console.error(error);
            });

            // Position the camera
            camera.position.z = 5;

            // Animation loop
            function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            if (scene.children.length > 1) { // Check if the heart model is loaded
            scene.children[1].rotation.y += 0.01; // Rotate the heart
            }
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
            animate();


Usually the disallowed MIME type("text/html") error means you are getting a html error page. Check the path you are loading.

The path is to the GLTFLoader.js file which is not an html file, so why I am getting html error? How to fix it?

Can you navigate to the path directly?... put the path in your broswer and see what is returned

No, I cannot directly navigate the path..

The major problem here is in the disallowed MIME type..how can the MIME type be changed? Plz help
